# What hook to use to redirect based on $post

Tags: hooks, redirect, actions

Trying to add an action to redirect based on if user is not logged in and is accessing certain post types. Problem is, during template_redirect, `$post` is NULL and other ones the headers seem to have already been sent so it won't redirect. What would be the appropriate action to use here?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mytheme_restrict_user_content' );
function mytheme_restrict_user_content(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $restrict = false;
        $restricted_post_types = array('documentlibrary', 'events');
        if ( in_array( $post->post_type, $restricted_post_types ) ){
            $restrict = true;
        }
        if ($restrict){
            auth_redirect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mytheme_restrict_user_content' );

function mytheme_restrict_user_content( $query ){
  $restricted_post_types = array('documentlibrary', 'events');
  if ( is_main_query() && is_singular($restricted_post_types) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $redirect = set_url_scheme('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url($redirect, true) );
    exit();
  }
}
```

I don't use `auth_redirect` because that function check if the user is logged in, but we already know that user is not logged in.

Comment: I liked that auth_redirect handles forwarding user to the correct page after in a little bundle.  with your code I get `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

Comment: Hi @Damon `pre_get_posts` is fired before `template_redirect`. So there is something in your installation that sent header too early. 100% problem is not my code. My code also forwarding user to the correct page after login, runs faster and is more compact than one you posted.

Comment: Also don't forget that rely on `template_redirect` you run the DB query. Relying on `pre_get_posts` DB query is not runned so it's much better for your scope.

Comment: Hm. Maybe this is Genesis framework shenanigans.

Comment: I put it back to template_redirect and it's working with your code now. danke

Comment: @Damon I think that a plugin or theme are hooking into `pre_get_posts` or earlier hook causing a problem. I've tested my code just now, hooking into `pre_get_posts`, and it works perfectly as a guessed. So, again, problem is elsewhere.